# how can I make game card animation in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

please, I want to make the card move to another card animation like the video

Example: https://www.veed.io/view/d0f4bfbe-fdf7-4d77-ab21-3263be24ca4b

Comment: it depends on what your are using, if you are using plain flutter I think the AnimatedPosition widget will do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use key for each card and get the position of each card on the screen

```
RenderBox box = key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
print(box.localToGlobal(offset.zero));//this will give you the offset of the widget where you want to move the card..
```

Once you get the offset move the position of the current card to that offset using Animated widgets. You may have to use an indexed Stack widget set cards in order and move cards above one another

If you wish to make it using packages take a look at flame

https://pub.dev/packages/flame